# PHP stripos not returning all positions

Tags: php, strpos

I am returning all the array where the `stripos` function matches like this

```
$requestedservice = request('service');
$result_array = array_filter($allservicesname, function($item) use ($requestedservice) {
return (stripos($item, $requestedservice) !== false);
        });
```

This only works for the first occurrence, e.g- if the haystack is `Walk dance and rock` if the needle is `Walk` it reutrns `Walk dance and rock`, but if the needle is `Walk rock` it does not return `Walk dance and rock`. Why is this happening?

Is there a way to find for all occurrences, so that, it matches the haystack `Walk dance and rock` with the needle `Walk rock`?

And also if the needle is `Walk run` it should not match `Walk dance and rock`, this is kind of normal use case

Comment: Everything is working as expected.  You'd need to call a separate `stripos()` for each word that may or may not be separated by other words/characters.  Maybe you'd like to use a regex solution like `preg_grep()`

Comment: As the php man says: stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string. So you can't find multiple occurrences with this function. The needle "Walk rock". is not a substring of "Walk dance rock", as @mickmackusa says you probably need to use a regexp

Comment: @Riccardo Any other solution to put `walk rock` to `walk dance rock`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/function.preg-match.php this should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you will be able to achieve your desired filtration with a loop of case-insensitive keyword checks.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91a0bdb05a9a1984b884d832acaa94cb860f455e))

```
$allservicesname=['dance','Walk rock','Walk dance and rock','Walk'];  // array of haystacks

$requestedservice='walk rock';  // string of needles

$result_array=array_filter($allservicesname,function($string)use($requestedservice){
    foreach(explode(' ',$requestedservice) as $keyword){
        if(stripos($string,$keyword)===false){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

var_export($result_array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'Walk rock',
  2 => 'Walk dance and rock',
)
```

Notice the original keys are preserved in the output array.  Also, I should mention that the keywords can appear in any order and maintain accuracy.

---

Alternatively, if you are not scared off by the idea of regex, `preg_grep()` can concisely perform this task.  It is the function that is designed to filter arrays using regex on each element.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/373b0dd0838159c9d61ec8c34bfcdf3cddec76fc)) ([Regex Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbwjLj/1))

```
$allservicesname=['Walk dance and rock walk','dance','walk','rock and walk','sidewalk and rockwall'];  // array of haystacks

$requestedservice='walk rock';  // string of needles
$pattern='/(?=.*\Q'.str_replace(' ','\E)(?=.*\Q',$requestedservice).'\E)/i';  // with literal substring matching, no wordboundaries
//$pattern='/(?=.*\b\Q'.str_replace(' ','\E\b)(?=.*\b\Q',$requestedservice).'\E\b)/i';  // with wordboundaries  
echo $pattern,"\n";

$result_array=preg_grep($pattern,$allservicesname);

var_export($result_array);
```

Output:

```
/(?=.*\Qwalk\E)(?=.*\Qrock\E)/i
array (
  0 => 'Walk dance and rock walk',
  3 => 'rock and walk',
  4 => 'sidewalk and rockwall',
)
```

If you don't want element `[4]` to qualify, then word boundaries are necessary - use the second (commented out) pattern declaration instead.

`\Q..\E` ensures that no characters with special meanings in regex can interfere with the execution.  The substrings inside of them are interpreted "literally".

Comment: Please explain how that is possible, because my demo links prove their success.  Can you post a demo link to me with sample data that breaks my methods?  I'll fix it up.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. But only problem I am having is that, it does not match special character like `&` or `'` how can I match for those too?

Comment: Are we talking about matching failures when processing html entities (`"`,`'`,`&`,`<`,`>`) ?  Sounds like a job for http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php If this doesn't solve your problem, please send me a demo link (like I have included in my answer) which reproduces the issue and I'll look into it.

Comment: It matches `walk - rock` with `walk rock` but does not match `walk - rock` with `walk - rock` I tried using `htmlentitydecode` as well, what could be the problem

Comment: Please give me your exact code in a demo link and I'll fix it.

Comment: There are several hyphen-looking characters.  If this is the hiccup, make sure the hyphen is the right kind of hyphen.  If you only want to search using the "words" in the search string, `str_word_count ()` can be a simple workaround for my first method.

Comment: `/(?=.*\b\Q'.str_replace(' ','\E\b)(?=.*\b\Q',$requestedservice).'\E\b)/i'`I am actually using this one, I could not replicate this issue on the regex tester.

Comment: I can't really help you without more information.  My methods should work because the demos prove them right.  I am happy to help if you can give me more to go on.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) only returns the first occurrence. After you turn the string into an array with [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you can use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to accomplish what you're looking for.

Here it is action:

```
$all_services = explode(" ", "walk dance and rock");
$requested_services = explode(" ", "walk rock");
$result_array = array();

foreach ($all_services as $service) {
    if (in_array($service, $requested_services)) {
        $result_array[] = $service;
    }
}
```